# Want a regex for dynamic URL

Tags: regex

I want regex for this dynamic URL:

```
http://dvc.domain.co.uk/tutorial/*tr*-*tutor*
```

I tried:

```
^https?:\/\/[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.dvc\.domain\.co\.uk\.tutorial\/'.'
```

**NOTE** the bold words could be anything as they are dynamic.

[stribiz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/stribizhev) is really problem solver, thanks buddy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have just digits in the first dynamic part, and any alphanumerics or underscores in the second part (and 1 hyphen), you can use the following regex:

```
https?:\/\/dvc\.domain\.co\.uk\/tutorial\/\d+\/\w+-\w+
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lL0eO3/1)

Note that if you are using `QRegularExpression`, you will need to double-escape slashes:

```
QRegularExpression re("https?:\\/\\/dvc\\.domain\\.co\\.uk\\/tutorial\\/\\d+\\/\\w+-\\w+");
```

**EDIT**:

To match the URL without digits, just remove the `\d+\/` part from the regex:

```
https?:\/\/dvc\.domain\.co\.uk\/tutorial\/\w+-\w+
```

See [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/lL0eO3/2)

Comment: thanks for your reply i have edidted and made the source url easier now pls have a look for that one and generate regex for same Thanks !!

Comment: What about if i could have any anything like (special characters, numbers, charatcter ie. ab^23&a) in place of first part ? instead just w+

Comment: You may use `[^\/]+` negated class to match anything but a `/`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help but i could not relate where i should put it?

Comment: If you want to match anything instead of `dvc.domain.co.uk`, you can just replace it with `[^\/]*`: [`https?:\/\/[^\/]*\/tutorial\/\w+-\w+`](https://regex101.com/r/lL0eO3/3)

Comment: but i want anything in place of first w+ in this url, i mean there could be any char, symbol, digit etc in place of first w+ then ??

Comment: Perhaps, [`https?:\/\/dvc\.domain\.co\.uk\/tutorial\/.*`](https://regex101.com/r/lL0eO3/4)? Or [`https?:\/\/dvc\.domain\.co\.uk\/tutorial\/[^-]*-\w+`](https://regex101.com/r/lL0eO3/5). It is difficult to help without concrete specifications.

Comment: no no, everything is like same as your provided in solution but rght now i m only able to put character and digits in place of first w+ part but now i want that there could be anything in place of first w+ then what expression should i use .ie. http://dvc.domain.co.uk/tutorial/xyz432-xyz
its working fine but http://dvc.domain.co.uk/tutorial/xyz$.432-xyz, is not valid because i have putted $ and. so i want that anything should be accespted here like alphanumeric, digits, characts anythig. thats it.

Comment: Ok, `.*` will match anything but a newline till the end of the line (1-line string). If you use `[^-]*-\w+`, it will match *0 or more characters other than `-` up to the first `-`, then 1 or more characters from the set of a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and _*.